# Не проходит POST запрос PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Не проходит POST запрос вот такого вида

```
$.ajax({
    url: "component_add_com_list.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

Отправляю данный запрос и массив `$_POST` в файле `component_add_com_list.php` не заполняется. Как только меняю `POST` на `GET`, то массив `$_GET` заполняется отлично!

Comment: `method:'POST'`?

Comment: Откройте Инспектор в браузере (F12 в Chrome) и перейдите на вкладку Network. После этого попробуйте еще раз инициировать отправку ajax-запроса и посмотреть, что там будет в нем в Headers, Preview, Response. Для просмотра этого добра нужно будет нажать на произведенный запрос, это в секции Name, там где собственно url запросов показывается.

Comment: Добавьте кода в вопрос - весь обработчик, где этот `$.ajax` вызывается и соответствующую разметку.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно начал изучать `ajax`. Столкнулся с такой же проблемой - не отправляется через форму. Присвоил каждому `input` свой `id` и забрал значения:

```
var x = $("#input-x").val();
var y = $("#input-y").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "component_add_com_list.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({varX: x, varY: y}),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

Отправлять стал не по `submit`, а по `click`.

Comment: Проблема была в localhost. А не в самом запросе. Сначала я использовал localhost из PhpShtorm, а потом попробовал запустить на OpenServer и все заработало. Не знаю почему так...

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вынести подготовку данных ($('form').serialize()) перед выполнение AJAX-запроса. возможно AJAX отправляет данные, которые еще не успели обработаться (такое часто встречается в асинхронном коде) и выставите небольшой таймаут перед выполнением AJAX-запроса:

```
var a = $('form').serialize();
setTimeout( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "component_add_com_list.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: a,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}, 50);
```

Comment: Не помогло.....

Comment: посмотрите что приходит на сервер и приходят ли данные вообще.

Comment: Да. Данные проходят, а вот пост массив все равно не заполняется

Comment: попробуйте вынести подготовку данных ($('form').serialize()) перед выполнение AJAX-запроса. возможно AJAX отправляет данные, которые еще не успели обработаться (такое часто встречается в асинхронном коде).

Comment: это что за вуду-совет?

Comment: правлю сообщение

Comment: Как Вы себе это представляете? Вызов `$('form').serialize()` вернулся, значение `а` присвоилось, а "данные ... не успели обработаться"?

Comment: Ребята, все расходимся. Проблема была в том, что я использовал localhost, который встроен в PHPShtorm... А запустив на OpenServer все заработало....